# Count Distinct Values by using more than one column in a table

Tags: sql-server

Please can you help me with the following query in MSSQL?

I will try and explain as best I can.

First keep in mind that all the columns in MyTable needs to be reported in the output report even though only three columns will be used to compare the data.

I have a table with MbrNo, DepCode and PracticeNo, now the Practice could have consulted with more than one MbrNo and with more than one DepCode from the same MbrNo. I require the Member/Dependent Count to be populated in an additional column whereby it reflects the amount of Members the doctor consulted. However the DepCode should also be considered. If the doctor consulted with 1 MbrNo but 3 different Dependent the count should then be 3, as the MbrNo is applicable to all 3 dependent and thus the practice consulted with three people.

---

### MY TABLE

```
    MbrNo | DepCode | PracticeNo | Adress | Email | TelNo
    123        01         A          XY      XY       XY
    1234       00         B          XY      XY       XY
    1234       00         B          XY      XY       XY
    1245       00         C          XY      XY       XY
    123        02         A          XY      XY       XY
    1234       02         B          XY      XY       XY
    1233       01         A          XY      XY       XY
    1233       00         B          XY      XY       XY
```

### OUTPUT REPORT

```
    MbrNo | DepCode | PracticeNo | Adress | Email | TelNo | MemberCount
    123        01         A          XY      XY      XY          3
    1234       00         B          XY      XY      XY          3 
    1234       00         B          XY      XY      XY          3
    1245       00         C          XY      XY      XY          1
    123        02         A          XY      XY      XY          3 
    1234       02         B          XY      XY      XY          3
    1233       01         A          XY      XY      XY          3
    1233       00         B          XY      XY      XY          3
```

Provider B = 3 MemberCount because the Provider Consulted the same member X 2 and the calculation it to confirm the People count. Also note that it should not be placed in order as my previous query that forms part of this query already orders the details accordingly.

I honestly have no idea how to spec this to get the desired results.

Hope the above makes sense and that someone can help me with it.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Is your Output correct?. I count 2 for `MbrNo = 123 and PracticeNo = A`, and 1 for `MbrNo = 1233 and PracticeNo = A` and 1 for `MbrNo = 1233 and PracticeNo = B`

Comment: You are correct but I want to count on Provider Number and Not Member Number, therefore Practice Number = A MbrNo = 123 (Dep01),123 (Dep02), and 1233 (Dep01) thus  gives count of 3 for Practice A

Comment: Do you want to count how many people a Provider saw? So Provider B saw DepCode 00 twice, but it should be counted as 1?

Comment: I've changed my answer

Answer (score 2):

Use [CROSS APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to count the unique matches:

Test data

```
DECLARE @t table
( MbrNo int, DepCode int, PracticeNo char(1), Adress char(2),
  Email char(2), TelNo char(2))

insert @t values
(123,'01','A','XY','XY','XY')
,(1234,'00','B','XY','XY','XY')
,(1234,'00','B','XY','XY','XY')
,(1245,'00','C','XY','XY','XY')
,(123,'02','A','XY','XY','XY')
,(1234,'02','B','XY','XY','XY')
,(1233,'01','A','XY','XY','XY')
,(1233,'00','B','XY','XY','XY')
```

Query for test data:

```
SELECT 
  t1.MbrNo,
  t1.DepCode,
  t1.PracticeNo,
  t1.Adress,
  t1.Email,
  t1.TelNo, 
  z.MemberCount
FROM @t t1
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT count(*) MemberCount 
   FROM (SELECT null x 
         FROM @t
         WHERE
           t1.PracticeNo = PracticeNo 
         GROUP BY MbrNo, DepCode)y)  z
```

Result:

```
MbrNo   DepCode PracticeNo  Adress  Email   TelNo   MemberCount
123     1       A           XY      XY      XY      3
1234    0       B           XY      XY      XY      3
1234    0       B           XY      XY      XY      3
1245    0       C           XY      XY      XY      1
123     2       A           XY      XY      XY      3
1234    2       B           XY      XY      XY      3
1233    1       A           XY      XY      XY      3
1233    0       B           XY      XY      XY      3
```

Comment: Like I said, more clever people. I was thinking about `CROSS APPLY` but I've never used it before. Well done

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, You want something like this:

```
SELECT MbrNo, DepCode, PracticeNo, Adress, Email, TelNo, c.total
FROM
 table t
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT MbrNo, DepCode, PracticeNo, count(*) as total
   FROM table
   GROUP BY (MbrNo, DepCode, PracticeNo)
) c on (c.MbrNo = t.MbrNo and c.DepCode = t.DepCode and c.PracticeNo = t.PracticeNo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've edited the answer to replace my previous answer, because this is the actual correct answer:

```
SELECT t.MbrNo, t.DepCode, t.PracticeNo, Adress, Email, TelNo, c.total
FROM
 table t
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT PracticeNo, SUM(total) total 
from
( SELECT MbrNo, DepCode, PracticeNo, count(distinct DepCode) as total
   FROM table
   GROUP BY MbrNo, DepCode, PracticeNo) a
GROUP BY PracticeNo
) c on (c.PracticeNo = t.PracticeNo)
```

I might be wrong, and there might be more clever people than me with SQL, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to get the Total per Practice No back without another view

This might be a better way though

```
;WITH aTable (MbrNo, DepCode, PracticeNo, total) 
AS
(
 SELECT MbrNo, DepCode, PracticeNo, count(distinct DepCode) as total
   FROM table
   GROUP BY MbrNo, DepCode, PracticeNo
)
SELECT t.MbrNo, t.DepCode, t.PracticeNo, Adress, Email, TelNo, (Select SUM(total) from aTable where PracticeNo = t.PracticeNo)
FROM
 table t
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the help I really appreciate it. I am sure that all the above queries work but it is a bit high level for me as I have only been working on SQL for like 3 months here and there.
So below is the route I have taken that also gives me the required results. It might not be the best but for now it is what I at least understand. 
I decided to create a unique number combining the MbrNo with the DepCode and Practice Number. Then did a count on the unique references and then joined the original table with the count onto a newer table again.

```
    ALTER TABLE
    Table1
    ADD 
    UniqueMemberDep2 VARCHAR(MAX) NULL

    UPDATE
    Table1
    SET UniqueMemberDep2 = CONCAT(MbrNo, DepNo, PracticeNo)

    SELECT 
    PracticeNo, COUNT(Distinct UniqueMemberDep2) as ProviderMemberCount
    INTO Temp
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY PracticeNo

    SELECT Table1.*, Temp.ProviderMemberCount
    into Table2 FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Temp on                 
    Table1.PracticeNo = Temp.PracticeNo

    Select * from Table2
    DROP TABLE Table1
    DROP TABLE Temp
```